# How can I convert 12 AM and PM hour time?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to convert AM and PM Hour,

here my code:

```
            new_lead_time_schedule = datetime.strptime(sale_order_line.order_id.date_order, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT) + timedelta(days=sale_order_line.customer_lead or 0.0)
            if sale_order_line.shift2 == 'morning':
                new_lead_time_schedule = fields.Datetime.context_timestamp(self, new_lead_time_schedule).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0).astimezone(utc)
            elif sale_order_line.shift2 == 'afternoon':
                new_lead_time_schedule = fields.Datetime.context_timestamp(self, new_lead_time_schedule).replace(hour=4, minute=0, second=0).astimezone(utc)
```

but in my data not changed, how to convert time AM and PM?

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try below process :

**Translations --> Language --> Edit**

**Replace time format : %H:%M:%S to %I:%M:%S %p**

import following:

**from odoo.tools import float_is_zero, float_compare, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT**

define in your function in place of time format **DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT**
i hope it helps you.